# ArrowChat (PHP) hosted on IIS with MS SQL Server

Tags: php, sql-server, chat

I am trying to test a trial version of ArrowChat on windows (using IIS and MS SQL Server). I have installed the extensions of MS SQL Server and when i connect using a PHP script, i get connected successfully. However, with Arrow chat it errors. It doesnt show any error details either.

Is there a way to see the log? I am not a PHP developer.
[image]